# zend framework : how to add the new file

Tags: php, zend-framework

i want to build new project with zendframe work and mvc application..

already i build the project using framework.zend.com.

further more i would like to include new php file to the project.

automatically index file created by zend frameworkd for this project.

so i want to include another php file to this project..

i dont know how to do this....

please any one..

Comment: http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf

Comment: Where you place a file to be used depends significantly upon what the code is for.  You need to flesh out this question.

Comment: hi 
i did take the example project from this link
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html.

there s one file which s first executed(index.php) in application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml

then i would like to add a new file.....

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start is the [quickstart guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)

It sounds like you want to create an new controller, creating new controllers/views is easy with [Zend_Tool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. You want to build you project using Zend Framework, as a MVC application, or you want to add some ZF's libraries to your own project?

Comment: yes i want to build my project using zend framework with mvc application....

please explain how to do this..

Comment: zendcast (http://www.zendcasts.com/) is a good source of basic steps showing how to start using zend framework. Also if official Zend Framework Quick Start is not enough, you can use some books on ZF. But you must remember, that ZF is not the easiest framework to start with. Maybe you could try other, simpler PHP frameworks (e.g. cakePHP).